# How to use mutate_all() with a function having multiple arguments

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) and I want to use the R mutate_all() function to apply a simple function with two arguments (shr() in my example) to all columns in the data frame. Below is my simple example of a data frame with 3 columns (my actual application has many more than 3 columns). I can get the result I want by using the mutate function repeatedly. And I can use the mutate_all() function successfully with a function having only one argument. But I cannot find the proper way to get the result with the mutate_all() function with a function having two or more arguments. Help appreciated.

I have tried many variations and I have read several Q's and A's on stackoverFlow, but have not been able to find the answer. For example, I tried working with "How to use multiple arguments in mutate_all for any function?" but I was unable to apply the answer successfully in my case.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(3,3,2,2),c=c(2,4,3,1))
shr <- function(x,y) { 
    z <- x/y 
}
df1 <- mutate(df,a=shr(a,b),c=shr(c,b),b=shr(b,b)) # Gives the      result I want
# df2 <- mutate_all(df, shr, ... ? # How to pass column b to this function?
```

Expected results:

```
          a b         c
1 0.3333333 1 0.6666667
2 0.6666667 1 1.3333333
3 1.5000000 1 1.5000000
4 2.0000000 1 0.5000000
```

Comment: In your real data, are you trying to divide all columns by one column as in the example? If so, `df / df$b` will do that.

Comment: Very helpful feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `mutate_all` like

```
dplyr::mutate_all(df, list(new = ~shr(., b)))

#  a b c a_new b_new c_new
#1 1 3 2 0.333     1 0.667
#2 2 3 4 0.667     1 1.333
#3 3 2 3 1.500     1 1.500
#4 4 2 1 2.000     1 0.500
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in `base R`

```
df[] <- Map(shr, df, df['b'])
df
#          a b         c
#1 0.3333333 1 0.6666667
#2 0.6666667 1 1.3333333
#3 1.5000000 1 1.5000000
#4 2.0000000 1 0.5000000
```

---

or in `tidyverse`

```
map2_df(df, df['b'], shr)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      a     b     c
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 0.333     1 0.667
#2 0.667     1 1.33 
#3 1.5       1 1.5  
#4 2         1 0.5
```